# How to iterate through a dynamic, rectangular matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-arithmetic, pointer-to-pointer

I have to create a matrix with pointers in dynamic memory in C, fill it with random numbers then print it.

This is part of a larger assignment from college (I had to do a whole library of functions for matrixes) but for the purposes of the post, I think I managed to track down and isolate the problematic bits. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 3;
    int **matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows); //declaring and allocating dynamic memory for the matrix

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        *(matrix+i) = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);

    //generating random numbers for the matrix:
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            *(*(matrix+j)+i) = rand() % 20;

    //printing matrix:
    printf("{\t");
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        int j;

        if(i>0)
            printf("\t");
        printf("{\t");

        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
            printf("%d\t",*(*(matrix + j) + i));

        printf("}");
        if(i<rows-1)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\t}\n\n");

    //destroying the matrix
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        free(matrix[i]);

    free(matrix);
    matrix = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

The debugger stops here:

`*(*(matrix+j)+i) = rand() % 20;`

Apparently, when trying to generate a random number for the first column of the second row (i.e. when it first changes rows) the debugger "cannot access memory" for that position, then the program crashes.

I tried changing the amount of rows and columns and I found it only crashes when row size is less than column size, which is weird because when it's equal or more, it works just fine.

I'm trying with 2 rows by 3 columns. Expectation:

```
{       {       5       17      3       }
        {       1       8       11      }       }
```

What actually happens:

`Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Values of the variables when the debugger stops (at generating random numbers):

```
i = 0
j = 2
**(matrix + 2) (aka matrix[0][2]) = Cannot access memory at address 0xabababababababab
```

At first I suspected I messed up when allocating memory for the matrix, but as I said when the matrix is square it does work fine, so I really don't know what's the issue here. I know the stackOverflow community doesn't like when someone posts "I don't know what I did wrong please help" kind of thing but I've really been a long time trying and couldn't get to the root of the problem.

Can someone please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: It seems you mean *(*(matrix+i)+j) = rand() % 20; instead of *(*(matrix+j)+i) = rand() % 20;

Comment: No way, it really was that? I thought that's how you iterated a matrix. I'll try and see if it fixes it. Can you please explain more? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Is the use of double pointers and the `*(matrix + i)` notation instead of `matrix[i]` mandatory in your assignment?

Comment: Usually storing the data in one array and accessing the values with `matrix[i*cols+j]` is easier to implement and more efficient

Comment: @OleMorud wow, I didn't know that! It is more simple to understand indeed. I'll try it and probably even use this way in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These nested for loops contain a bug

```
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        *(*(matrix+j)+i) = rand() % 20;
```

The pointer `matrix` points to an array of pointers that in turn point to "rows". So the expression `matrix + i` points to the `i-th` "row". However instead you are using the index `j`.

That is you need to write

```
*(*(matrix+i)+j) = rand() % 20;
```

instead of

```
*(*(matrix+j)+i) = rand() % 20;
```

Otherwise when the value of `cols` is greater than the value of `rows` the expression `matrix + j` can access memory outside the allocated array of pointers (rows).

The same problem exists in this call of printf

```
 printf("%d\t",*(*(matrix + j) + i));
```

where you have to write

```
 printf("%d\t",*(*(matrix + i) + j));
```

That is you need actually to access an element `matrix[i][j]`. This expression may be rewritten like

```
( *( matrix + i ) )[j]
```

that in turn may be rewritten like

```
*( *( matrix + i ) + j )
```

Or in other way it may be rewritten like

```
*( matrix[i] + j )
```

and then

```
*( *( matrix + i ) + j )
```

To raise your interest to the subscript operator investigate these equivalent expressions to access elements of a two-dimensional array declared for example like

```
T a[M][N];
```

The expressions are

```
a[i][j]
i[a][j]
j[a[i]]
j[i[a]]
*( *( a + i ) + j )
*( a[i] + j )
*( i[a] + j )
( *( a + i ) )[j]
j[*( a + i ) ]
```

Comment: Thank you all, you're very kind. Yes, it seems I mixed up the order of i and j when accessing the value of the matrix in a given position. I didn't have to use pointer notation for the assignment, @Bob__, but as a means to keep learning I wanted to see if I could implement pointers and dynamic memory into it. Thank you Vlad for pointing out such a silly mistake of mine.